# Pass string in jquery to asp.net mvc ActionResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following jquery code.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function FillOption() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/contratoBuscar/GetItem/",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#mydrop').append('<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option > ');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I would like to pass a string to my GetItem fonction from the follwing cshtml field

```
@Html.TextBox("selected_cliente_contrato", Model.selected_cliente_contrato, new { @id = "clienteContratoAutocomplete", @type = "text", @placeholder = "clientes", @class = "form-control" })
```

Here is the code for my controller
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetItem(string clienteName)
        {

```
        contratoBuscarModel contrato = new contratoBuscarModel();
        contrato.selected_cliente_contrato = clienteName;
        contratoBuscarContext contratoBuscar = new contratoBuscarContext();

        clienteContratosContext clienteContratosContext = new clienteContratosContext();

        List<SelectListItem> drop = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (contratoModel contract in contratoBuscar.GetAllContratosFiltrar(contrato).contratosFound)
        {
            drop.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = contract.numero_contrato,
                Value = contract.numero_contrato
            });
        }

        return Json(drop);
    }
```

My question is how can I get the clienteName from  my htmlTextBox pass it in the jquery so I can use it in my actionResult. I have tried many times and my clienteName keeps being null. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your url line, change it to the following:

`url: "/contratoBuscar/GetItem?clienteName=" + $("#clienteContratoAutocomplete").val()`

primitive types for some reason do not work if passed in in data field so you have to pass them in in the url. Assuming default routes, since `string clienteName` is not `id`, you have to pass it like a get parameter `?varname=value`.